# string manipluator to use all function in c++

Tags: c++

> Write a program to manipulate strings. In this program take a whole paragraph with punctuations (up to 500 letters) either input from user, initialize or read from file and provide following functionalities within a class:
>
> a) Declare class Paragraph_Analysis
>
> b) Member Function: SearchWord (to search for a particular word)
>
> c) Member Function: SearchLetter (to search for a particular letter)
>
> d) Member Function: WordCount (to count total words)
>
> e) Member Function: LetterCount (ONLY to count all letters e.g ‘A’,’a’)
>
> f) Member Function: FindReplaceWord (to find and replace a word)
>
> g) Member Function: FindReplaceLetter (to find and replace a letter)
>
> h) Member Function: Summary (to display summary of frequency of each letter within the paragraph)
>
> i) Of course, a menu is expected by user to know about available functionalities of your Paragraph_Analysis application.

Tried code below however i need switch so that user can try various function and user can enter paragraph

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
using namespace std;

char str[100] = "This string contains many alphabets";
char paragraph,sentence;

void SearchWord(){
  string paragraph;

    cout << "Please enter your paragraph:";
    getline (cin,paragraph);

    cout << "Hello, your paragraph is " << paragraph << "!\n";
    string paragraph1 = paragraph;

//  cout << sentence << endl;
    cout << "The size of your paragraph = " << paragraph.size() << " characters. \n\n";
    string word;


    cout << "Please enter the word you are searching for:";
        getline (cin,word);
        cout << "Hello, your word is " << word << "!\n";
    size_t found = paragraph.find(word);

bool wordsearch = true;
while (paragraph.find(word) != string::npos)  {


  if (paragraph.find(word) == string::npos)
 cout << "" << word << " does not exist in the sentence" << endl;
        std::size_t found = paragraph.find(word);

  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "'word' found at: " << found << '\n';


    break;

    }while (wordsearch = true);



}

void SearchLetter(){

}

void WordCount(){
  int i,count=1;

    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';++i)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
            count++;
    }

    cout<<"\nThere are "<<count<<" words in the given string";
}
void LetterCount(){

}

void FindReplaceWord(){

}

void FindReplaceLetter(){

}
void Summary(){
  int i = 0, alphabet[26] = {0}, j;
   while (str[i] != '\0') {
      if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
         j = str[i] - 'a';
         ++alphabet[j];
      }
      ++i;
   }
   cout<<"frequency of all alphabets in the string is:"<<endl;
   for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
      cout<< char(i + 'a')<<" : "<< alphabet[i]<< endl;

}


int main()
{
  // WordCount();
  //SearchLetter()
 // SearchWord();
 //  Summary(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions It is unclear how someone could answer your question without doing your homework for you

Comment: @DCTID I tried this code but working with switch statements and some functions i am newbie so trying to understand aswell learn if you can help that would be appreciated

Comment: it is unclear what you want the switch to do and what error you get. Read the link about asking homework questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @DCTID switch will use use all those member functions which are described in program that is searchword search letter all those functions and will call those function as user will enter the number if user wants yo exit the program should have exit number in switch which will tale user to screen and say thanks bye

Comment: If you want to learn to write a switch, write a very simple program that uses a switch; examples are all over the web. If you want to learn I/O, search for "C++ I/O". Don't try to learn them in the context of a complicated program that does many other things.

Comment: Many of your functions can be completed simply by visiting [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and paying attention to the `.size()` and `.find()` member function for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is a typical menu selection. You show the user a list of actions that he can select. Each action has an associated digit or letter that you show in the menu.

Then you read from `std::cin` the wished selection. So a letter or a digit or a number, whatever is shown in the menu.

Then you use the C++ `switch` statement. The C++ switch statement takes a variable, for example a char or an int as its parameter. Then, there are many case clauses. In each case clause you define, what should happen, if the "case" is fullfilled. Example. The user enters an integer number. Like in `int selection; std::cin>>selection;` and now you can evaluate this interger in the different case statements. For example: `case 1:`. if the selection is 1, then the code, following the case statement is executed. Until the `break;` statement comes.

You can have as many `case` statements as you wish. But no doubles and only with constants that are fitting to your selection-variable's type.

This `switch` construct saves you from lengthy if then else if then else if then else .. . . statements.

In the below code I have implemented such a menu with selection and a big "switch case" loop. You can select all functions, which will be executed with the requested functionality.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

// Some test data. This is the same, as if this data would be in a file
std::istringstream inputTestFileLong{ R"(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, arcu est nonummy molestie 
vel magna porttitor. Eget vel integer, turpis condimentum ante, integer elit dolor, cum necessitatibus, 
vel proin. Risus nec arcu rutrum malesuada mauris, fringilla viverra, augue luctus praesentium erat 
elit aenean. Praesent ligula fringilla justo, magna sed wisi, nibh vel vel semper nostrud, vestibulum 
enim vel orci. Pulvinar eget feugiat est, exercitationem ut dui, nascetur dui, condimentum aliquam libero. 
Nunc ullamcorper malesuadamum, justo consectetuer odio quis consequat, mauris morbi, proin vivamus. Augue 
nulla cum, justo vehicula pede cursus nullam donec, fringilla tellus, massa parturient sed elementum, 
vestibulum sit egestas libero dignissim in ut.)" };

// Some additional test data. This is the same, as if this data would be in a file
std::istringstream inputTestFileShort{ "Lorem ipsum dolor" };


// We want to deal with a maximum number of characters
constexpr size_t MaxNumberOfCharacters = 500;
// We will use regurlar expressions to identify a word
const std::regex regexWord("[A-Za-z]+");


// Our Paragraph_Analysis class. All methods and data are define here
class Paragraph_Analysis
{
public:
    // Constructors
    Paragraph_Analysis() {};  // Default, empty. Member variables are already initialized in function body
    Paragraph_Analysis(std::istream& is) { readFromStream(is); }        // Read from a stream
    Paragraph_Analysis(std::string& data) { assignNewString(data); }    // Take a filename, open file and read data from there

    // Search for a word and report, if found or not
    bool searchWord(const std::string& word) { return (paragraph.find(word) != std::string::npos); }

    // Search for a character and report, if found or not
    bool searchCharacter(const char c) { return (paragraph.find(c) != std::string::npos); }

    // Count the words according to the definition, what a word is. Please see regex above
    void wordCount();

    // Count how many letters from the alphabet are in the paragraph
    void letterCount() { std::cout << "\n\nNumber of letters: " << std::count_if(paragraph.begin(), paragraph.end(), ::isalpha) << "\n"; }

    // Find a word in the text and replace it with another one
    void findReplaceWord(const std::string& find, const std::string& replace);

    // Find a character in the text and replace it with another one
    void findReplaceLetter(const char find, const char replace) { findReplaceWord(std::string(1, find), std::string(1, replace)); }

    // Count the frequency of all letters
    void frequencyOfLetter();

    // Open a file and read the text from the file
    void readFromFile(const std::string filename) { std::ifstream ifs(filename); if (ifs) readFromStream(ifs); else std::cerr << "\n*** ERROR\n"; }

    // Copy the paragraph from another string
    void assignNewString(const std::string& s) { paragraph.assign(s, 0, MaxNumberOfCharacters); }

    // Overwrite inserter and extractor operator for ultra simple input and output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Paragraph_Analysis& pa) { return os << pa.paragraph; }
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Paragraph_Analysis& pa) { pa.readFromStream(is); return is; }

protected:
    // Read text from a stream with a given maximum number
    void readFromStream(std::istream& is);

    // This is our data container
    std::string paragraph{};

    // Temproray string to hold converted strings
    std::string modifiedString{};

    // This we will use for counting characters
    std::map<char, unsigned int> letterCounter{};
};



// Read data from a stream. But only up to a limited count
void Paragraph_Analysis::readFromStream(std::istream& is)
{
    // First clear the old data
    paragraph.clear();

    // Read characters. Check for maximum count and for read errors
    char c{};
    while ((paragraph.size() < MaxNumberOfCharacters) && (is.get(c))) 
        paragraph.push_back(c); // Append new read character to paragraph
}

// Count the words in the paragraph
void Paragraph_Analysis::wordCount()
{
    // We will use the std::sregex_token iterator. This is an iterator, that looks
    // for things iour paragraph that are defined in the regex above. So, it will 
    // iterate over all words in the paragraph. It will start with the firts word 
    // and it will end with the last word. The distance betwenn the positions of
    // the first last word and the first word, is the number of words.
    std::cout << "\n\nNumber of words: "
        << std::distance(
               std::sregex_token_iterator(paragraph.begin(), paragraph.end(), regexWord, 1), // First word
               std::sregex_token_iterator())  // Last word
        << "\n";
}

// For replacing strings there is an existing function. We will simply use it.
void Paragraph_Analysis::findReplaceWord(const std::string& find, const std::string& replace)
{
    // Replace string
    modifiedString = std::regex_replace(paragraph, std::regex(find), replace);
    // Show result
    std::cout << "\n\nReplace '" << find << "' in original string with '"
        << replace << ". Result:\n\n" << modifiedString << "\n";

}

// Count the frequency of letters
void Paragraph_Analysis::frequencyOfLetter()
{
    // We use a std::map. Elements that are not in the map will be created by []
    // Clear previous count
    letterCounter.clear();
    // Simply add and count all letters
    for (char c : paragraph)
        ++letterCounter[c];

    // Show result to user
    std::cout << "\n\nCount of all characters in text:\n\n";
    // Some special care must be taken for none printables. We will show this as hex values starting wit 0x
    // Iterate over all pairs consisting of letter and corresponding count
    for (const auto lc : letterCounter) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        // Check for none printables and handle accordingly
        if (isprint(lc.first)) 
            oss << lc.first;
        else 
            oss << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<int>(lc.first);
        // Show final result
        std::cout << "Count of '" << oss.str() << "'    --> " << lc.second << "\n";
    }
}

// Read users choice. Check for valid data
int getMenuSelection()
{
    // Show menu
    std::cout << "\n\nChoose an option:\n   0 - Input Data\n   1 - Read data from file\n" <<
        "   2 - Display data\n   3 - Search for word\n   4 - Search for letter\n" <<
        "   5 - Count words\n   6 - Count letters from alphabet\n   7 - Find and replace a word\n" <<
        "   8 - Find and replace a letter\n   9 - Frequency of letters\n   10 - Exit the program\n--> ";

    // Here we will store the selection
    unsigned int selection{ 10 };
    // As long as there is no good selection, we will read a number
    bool noGoodSelection = true;
    while (noGoodSelection) {
        // Read selection. Check if valid
        noGoodSelection = (!(std::cin >> selection) || (selection > 10));
        // If not, show message and read again
        if (noGoodSelection) {
            std::cout << "Invalid Option , Try again" << '\n';
            std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore();
        }
    }
    return selection;
}


int main()
{
    // Instantiate our class and fill it with default data
    Paragraph_Analysis pa{ inputTestFileLong };

    // Some test code start -------------------------------------------
    // inputTestFileLong >> pa;
    //std::cout << pa;
    // pa.wordCount();
    // pa.letterCount();
    // pa.findReplaceWord(std::string("vel"), std::string("HELLO"));
    // pa.findReplaceLetter('o', '*');
    // pa.frequencyOfLetter();
    // Some test code end ---------------------------------------------

    // We will give the user to select an action
    unsigned int selection{ 0 };
    do {
        // Show the menu and get a selection from the user
        selection = getMenuSelection();

        // Depending on what the user selected
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 0:
            {   // Let the user enter data
                std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter data.  Type backslash '\\' to end input:\n";
                std::string newData{}; char c;
                while (std::cin.get(c) && (c != '\\') && (newData.size() < MaxNumberOfCharacters))
                    newData.push_back(c);
                pa.assignNewString(newData);
                // Show new data
                std::cout << "\n\nNew data:\n\n" << pa;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            {   // Read data from a file. Get filename, open file, then read
                std::cout << "\n\nRead from file: Please enter filename:\n";
                std::string filename{};
                if (std::cin >> filename)
                    pa.readFromFile(filename);
                // Show new data
                std::cout << "\n\nNew data:\n\n" << pa;
            }
            break;
        case 2:  // Show data in our class rto user
            std::cout << "\n\nData:\n\n" << pa;
            break;
        case 3:
            {   // Search a word
                std::cout << "\n\nSearch word: Please enter word:\n";
                std::string word{};
                bool wordExists{ false };
                if (std::cin >> word)
                    pa.searchWord(word);
                std::cout << "\n\n" << (wordExists ? "Word found" : "Word not found") << "\n";
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            {   // Search a character
                std::cout << "\n\nSearch character: Please enter character:\n";
                char character{};
                bool characterExists{ false };
                if (std::cin >> character)
                    pa.searchCharacter(character);
                std::cout << "\n\n" << (characterExists ? "Character found" : "Character not found") << "\n";
            }
            break;
        case 5:   // Show the word count
            pa.wordCount();
            break;
        case 6:   // Show the letter count
            pa.letterCount();
            break;
        case 7:
            {   // Search and replace a word
                std::cout << "\n\nFind and Replace word: Please enter word to find and replace-string:\n";
                std::string wordToFind{}, replaceString{};
                if (std::cin >> wordToFind >> replaceString)
                    pa.findReplaceWord(wordToFind, replaceString);
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            {   // Search and replace a charcater
                std::cout << "\n\nFind and Replace letter: Please enter letter to find and replace-letter:\n";
                char letterToFind{}, replaceLetter{};
                if (std::cin >> letterToFind >> replaceLetter)
                    pa.findReplaceLetter(letterToFind, replaceLetter);
            }
            break;
        case 9:   // Show the frequency of all characters
            pa.frequencyOfLetter();
            break;
        case 10:   // Exit program
            std::cout << "\n\nLeaving program. Thank you!\n\n";
            break;
        default:   // Should never happen. We check anyway.
            std::cerr << "Invalid selection\n";
        }
    } while (selection != 10); // Slection 10 will end the loop

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks arminMontigny appreciated and trying to understand what i was doing wrong